# ¿Como controlar componente de windows form c# desde biblioteca de clases?

Tags: c#

Buenos días y sobre todo gracias de ante mano. Os cuento a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

Tengo una aplicación windows form c#, de la cual en la solución también tengo un proyecto de biblioteca de clases donde se ejecutan varios métodos que se invocan desde el formulario.

El formulario que tengo es sencillo, tengo un RichTextBox en el que me gustaría mostrar la actividad que se va haciendo en el proceso que se ejecuta en la biblioteca de clases, en modo consola de actividad a tiempo real.

¿Es posible modificar el componente del formulario desde el proyecto de tipo biblioteca de clases?

Muchisimas gracias de antemano!!!

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!